# Nuxtjs Vuex not saving changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have data between sessions that is saved in `window.localStorage`. When a new session starts a plugin will grab the data and add it to the store.

```js
// ./store/data.js

export const state = () => ({
  data: []
})

export const mutations = {
  addItemToData (state, item) {
    state.data = state.data.push(item)
  },
  setData (state, data) {
    state.data = data
  },
}
```

```js
// ./store/index.js

import localStorage from '../plugins/localStorage'

export const plugins = [localStorage]
```

```js
// plugins/localStorage.js

const localStorage = store => {

  store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {

    if (mutation.type === 'data/addItemToData') {
      console.log('saving added item to storage')
      window.localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(state.data.data))
    }

  })

  // called when the store is initialized
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (window.localStorage.data) {
      store.commit('data/setData', JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data')))
    }
  }
}

export default localStorage
```

I've thrown all sorts of console statements in, and they all seem to output what they should. The data is in the localStorage, the mutations are firing, but after all that the data isn't in the store.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several things that do not make sense and that you can resolve

#### #1

```js
addItemToData (state, item) {
  state.data = state.data.push(item)
}
```

[`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does not return anything, so it should be written as

```js
addItemToData (state, item) {
  state.data.push(item)
}
```

#### #2

in your `localStorage.js` file, when you initialize the data storage, you are assuming that a `data` variable exists:

```js
if (window.localStorage.data) { ...
```

but that will never exist from the code you show, as you are adding the data to another variable

```js
window.localStorage.setItem('cart', ...
```

either change `cart` into `data` or `data` into `cart`

#### #3

If still does not work, I would suspect that your plugin is running before the `store` is actually initialized, for that, make sure you wait a moment before attempt to fill the store with the localStorage data

something like

```js
   ...
   if (window.localStorage.data) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       store.commit('data/setData', JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data')))
     }, 500)
   }
```

---

Working example is available on [Netlify](https://distracted-keller-a41f34.netlify.app/) and code on [GitHub](https://github.com/balexandre/so64616785)

Comment: Sorry, I copied this out from the code and changed a few names, looks like I missed some. I'll edit the post.

Comment: code available on [Git](https://github.com/balexandre/so64616785), working example on [Netlify](https://distracted-keller-a41f34.netlify.app/) ... just add some data, and refresh the page.. you will see it will read from local storage

Comment: So solution 3 worked. I don't love waiting some arbitrary amount of time like that though. Any ideas on how to check if the store is initialized?

Comment: you have a good base now, try to find out for yourself what more can you do ... remember NuxtJs community is also available on [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/ps2h6QT) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/nuxt_js)

Answer (score 0):

you can use vuex-persistedstate for saving in localstorage

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` Returns the `length` of the Array after insertion, In your case, it overrides the `data` Array to `Number` when you make a mutation. Do like the following..

```
export const state = () => ({
  data: []
})

export const mutations = {
  addItemToData (state, item) {
    state.data.push(item)
    // OR 
    state.data = [...state.data, item]
  },
  setData (state, data) {
    state.data = data
  },
}
```

And also make sure, you have data in localStorage.

```
 try { // handles if any parsing errors
   const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data')
   store.commit('data/setData', data)
 } catch(err) {
   console.log('JSON parsing error', err)
 }
```